# Microsoft Azure Active Directory can not add user

Tags: azure, entra-id

I've encountered a problem with Azure that I can neither properly comprehend nor solve. Perhaps one of you has already experienced something similar and can give me a tip.

I would explain the problem as follows:
An employee created an AAD for testing purposes, which runs on the company's domain. (@biz.tld)
Now another AAD has been created (@azurebiz.tld) in which various cloud offers are made available, the problem occurs when I want to invite a user to the new AAD that has the same domain as the already existent AAD with (@biz.tld).

The user is invited as a guest into the new AAD, then receives the invitation e-mail, but cannot log in because Microsoft does specify the correct e-mail in the invitation process (felix.fischer@biz.tld), but reports back that this account does not exist. 
Behind this eMail is a full Microsoft account, to which also an MSDN developer license is attached, with the felix.fischer@biz.tld you can also log into portzal.azure.com and have access to your free Azure budget.

My azure portal:
[image]

And this happens if I try to accept the invitation to the new AAD with my eMail (i can also not choose private or business account in this form):

[image]

If I try to resend my passwort in the invitation process I get the information, that my account does not exist:

[image]

That seems to me a huge shortcoming and I don't think I'm the first one to come across this problem.
Has anyone ever experienced this problem and solved it? Or does understand what happens here and would like explain it to me?

Comment: One thing I want to comfirm is that If one domina has been verified in one tenant, you cannot invite uses with this domain as a guest. So, you can explain which account is a member with a verified domain and which account is the guest user?

Comment: Uhm, it is more like I can not login with my real account because the invitation process always seems to not choose my microsoft account but looks in another aad where my account is not created - the aad with the same @domain.tld like my microsoft account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a Microsoft account with the same email address as an Azure AD account is a bad idea, and you cannot actually do it any longer. If you try and create a new Microsoft account with the same ID as an existing Azure AD domain it will not let you.
There isn't really a great solution to this other than changing the name of the Microsoft account to use a different email.

Comment: The solution that has just been presented to me amounts to replicating users from the internal AD to the AAD and transferring the subscription to the new accounts via the Microsoft Partner Portal (not quite certain), which overall have the same ID in the end. This is just crazy.